# Unable to scrape product title from Amazon

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to get the price and title of produts on [this Amazon website](https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/). No issues to extract the price, but I have issues with the title. The difference is I see "aria-hidded=true" in the class attribute. Here is the example.

```html
<div class="p13n-sc-truncated" aria-hidden="true" data-rows="2" title="Igloo ICEB26HNAQ Automatic Self-Cleaning Portable Electric Countertop Ice Maker Machine With Handle, 26 Pounds in 24 Hours, 9 Ice Cubes Ready in 7 minutes, With Ice Scoop and Basket">Igloo ICEB26HNAQ Automatic Self-Cleaning Portable Electric Countertop Ice Maker Machine…</div>
```

Here is the css selector command:

```
title = response.css('.p13n-sc-truncated').css('::text').extract()
```

May I know what the CSS selector should be to extract the text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by **XPATH**.
Go [xpather](http://xpather.com/) and send your html there and extract your xpath patterns.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
class SSDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "SSD_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0']
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
                'title': response.xpath('//div[@class="p13n-sc-truncated"][1]').extract(),
              }
```

[image]

Try to use beautiful soup:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install lxml 
apt-get install python-lxml
```

Beautiful Soup also relies on a parser, the default is lxml

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://your_amazon_link/product/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
for title in soup.select("ol#zg-ordered-list > li"):
    title_name = title.select_one(".p13n-sc-truncated").get_text()
    print(title_name)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I am building a solution using scrapy hence I would appreciate if there is a recommendation for scrapy. Thank you

Comment: Is it your link? https://www.amazon.com/Igloo-ICEB26HNWHN-Automatic-Self-Cleaning-Countertop/dp/B07XS8MCJ2

Comment: No. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: I meant your link which you gonna get title from it.

Comment: yes, it is one of the products from the best sellers page

Comment: here is the link to the page: https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

Comment: I edited my new answer by the aid of xpather, please test it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the following code and it still returns null value for the title. Here is the code class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'details'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.com']
    #start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-books-Amazon/zgbs/books']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0']
    def parse(self, response):
        obj = TutorialItem()
        title = response.xpath('//div[@class="p13n-sc-truncated"][1]').get()
        obj['title'] = title
        yield obj

Comment: @MahsaHassankashi Your Scrapy-code produces errors, watch your nested quotes in the xpath-selector. Also after adjusting the quotes the result is still empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. @carpo_jo solution worked. Mahsa, Appreciate you taking time to look into my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the html source code (ctrl + u) you will see that the product titles do have another class `p13n-sc-line-clamp-2` which works perfectly fine. So your css-selector could look like this:

```py
response.css('.p13n-sc-line-clamp-2::text').get().strip()
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class amaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'amatitle'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{'title': response.css('.p13n-sc-line-clamp-2::text').get().strip()}
```

If you want to extract all titles and strip them from the leading and trailing white-spaces change the parse-function to the following:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.css('.p13n-sc-line-clamp-2::text').getall()
        titles_strip = [x.strip() for x in titles]
        yield{'titles': titles_strip}
```

Comment: code is working as expected. added a minimal minimal working example.

Comment: @_carao_jo I tried and still null could you send screen shot from result?

Comment: @MahsaHassankashi here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9AVr.png

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine:

```py
>>> from parsel import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text='<div class="p13n-sc-truncated" aria-hidden="true" data-rows="2" title="Igloo ICEB26HNAQ Automatic Self-Cleaning Portable Electric Countertop Ice Maker Machine With Handle, 26 Pounds in 24 Hours, 9 Ice Cubes Ready in 7 minutes, With Ice Scoop and Basket">Igloo ICEB26HNAQ Automatic Self-Cleaning Portable Electric Countertop Ice Maker Machine…</div>')
>>> selector.css('.p13n-sc-truncated').css('::text').extract()
['Igloo ICEB26HNAQ Automatic Self-Cleaning Portable Electric Countertop Ice Maker Machine…']
```

My guess is that the response does not contain the expected HTML. If this is Amazon, that is extremely likely. They have quite some antibot measures in place.